# Nested Managed Paths

Tags: site-collection

Should be an easy one for the sharepoint pros out there:

Is it possible to nest a managed path under another managed path...all the theory i know up to this point tells me to no, but so far but nothing has told me for sure if it is possible or not.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I think I can actually answer this on my own, now that I've done some more digging:

Technically you can create a managed path for say `/sites/`, then if you wanted to create managed paths under that you could do `/sites/portals` or `/sites/teams` and bury collections under each of those paths along with also burying collections under `/sites/`.

You cannot, however, create a site collection in this example under `/sites/` called "Portals", because once you create the managed path `/sites/portals/` it is marked as reserved.